# Newly planted pine tree saplings

Tags: landscaping, pines

What are the best ways to care for my new baby loblolly pine trees? Thank you!

Comment: Are they in the ground already?  How old?  Got a picture?

Answer (score 6):

Mulch around the tree frequently, and pull out any small plants growing at the base of it.
Only water if soil is dry, because overwatering is a major killer.
Only prune dead or diseased branches.
To protect it from animals a plywood sunscreen can also protect it from insects.
However if you live with large animals like deers, you  may need a plastic tube or chicken wire fence to protect it.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer?  Link only answers don't add as much value to the site as a written answer.

Comment: I have updated it